# $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)=\emptyset \Leftrightarrow A=B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could you help to prove this, I just rewrite this as followed

$(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)=\emptyset \Leftrightarrow A=B$

Let $x\in (A\setminus B)\implies x\in A$ and $x\notin B$ (By definition of subtraction of set). This means $(A\setminus B)=(A\cap\overline B)$

$x\in (B\setminus A)\implies x\in B$ and $x\notin A$ . This means $(B\setminus A)=(B\cap\overline A)$

So $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)=\emptyset \Leftrightarrow (A\cap\overline B)\cup(B\cap\overline A)=\emptyset$

What should I do next to prove that $A=B$?

Comment: you can show that $A\subset B$ and $B\subset A$.

$A\subset B$: if $x\in A$ then .... so $x\in B$.
$B\subset A$: if $x\in B$ then .... so $x\in A$.

Comment: proof by contradiction will make it easier. Assume there exist x that belongs to $A$ but not $B$. then show that the conclusion is False

Comment: at the last line you can continue as follows. $(A\cap\overline B)\cup(B\cap\overline A)=\emptyset$ implies $(A\cap\overline B) = \emptyset$ and $(B\cap\overline A) = \emptyset$ which again implies $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$ and so on

Comment: Also: $A\Delta B\equiv(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly if $A=B$ then obviously $(A\setminus B) = \emptyset$ and $(B\setminus A)=\emptyset$. so the conclusion follows.

Secondly if $(A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)=\emptyset $
then $(A\setminus B)= \emptyset$ and $(B\setminus A)=\emptyset$

Now assume to the contrary that there exist $x$ that belongs to $A$ but not to $B$.
Then this would not have been true. That is $(A\setminus B)= \{x\}$ Thus the conclusion follows.

Comment: I thought the union means "OR" instead of "AND": $(A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)=\emptyset $
then $(A\setminus B)= \emptyset$ OR $(B\setminus A)=\emptyset$

Comment: If two things added gives empty set then obviously both are empty. Things do not cancel out in here. But you are right there are cases where UNION corresponds to OR. $A \cup B = C$ corresponds to $x \in A$ or $x \in B$ then $x \in C$

Comment: Please mark it as answer if that answered your question.

Comment: I already did it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below a proof making use of the principle of explosion ( " a contradiction implies anything") and also of RAA ( reductio ad absurdum: " anything implying a contradiction is false").

The " T " turned upside down means " Falsum " , " falsity" , that is " logical falsehood" or " contradiction".

This symbol can be written (1) after any self-contradictory statement such as " x belongs to the empty set", or (2) after any sequence containing  2 statements ( not necessarily consecutive) that contradict  each other.

[image]